# Why does my image resize code always product a completely black output image?

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing

I'm trying to resize an image. I thought it was a simple task...

Here's my code (note, the two `Save` calls are just for debugging to illustrate the problem):

```
    var newSize = new Size { Width = 450, Height = 250 };
    using (var img = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(sourceImageFilename))
    {
        var outputImage = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height);

        // Save input image for debugging (screenshot below)
        img.Save(@"M:\Coding\Photos\Temp\input.jpg");

        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            gr.DrawImage(outputImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height));
        }

        // Save output image for debugging (screenshot below)
        outputImage.Save(@"M:\Coding\Photos\Temp\output.jpg");
    }
```

This appears to be the exact same code a ton of people are using (and exists on SO in many answers). However, here's what the two images that are being written to disk look like:

[image: Bad image resize]

The original image is 5344x3006 and `newSize` (and the black output image) are 450x250.

All my other code is working fine (reading pixels from the input image with SetPixel, etc.), it's just this resize that's broken. Doing the resize with the `Bitmap` constructor is fine (but a bad quality resize).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the graphics from the OutputImage.

```
public static Bitmap Scale(this Bitmap inputImage, Size newSize)
{
    var outputImage = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height);

    inputImage.Save(@"M:\Coding\Photos\Temp\input.jpg");
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(outputImage))
    {
        gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        gr.DrawImage(inputImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height));
    }
    outputImage.Save(@"M:\Coding\Photos\Temp\output.jpg");

    return outputImage;
}
```